# Looking for Windows 8 Metro Style app Calendar control to use in my application

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-metro

Could you please point me at some existing calendar controls in HTML/JS, which I can imbed into my application?

I design an educational app and I need to use a Calendar like Metro Calendar , I found some Calendars but trail like devExpress. so any suggestions to design a calender like this or are there any samples for calendar control and why most of Jquery calender doesn't compatible with metro.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a JavaScript file that can act as a Calendar. Try:-
http://javascriptcalendar.org/

Comment: it seems good but are there any alternatives like metro calendar app ?

Comment: I'm not sure. Sorry I can't help you anymore.